# Why is OpenCV VideCapture(0) not working on a Mac OS?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, face-detection

I have a MacBook Air M1 2020, Ventura, 13.1 OS.
This is my code to capture a video

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

writer = cv2.VideoWriter('video_out.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v'),12, (width, height))
while True: 
    
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    
    frame = detect_face(frame)
    
    writer.write(frame)

    cv2.imshow('Video Face Detection', frame) 
 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break 
        
cap.release() 
writer.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The detect face function.

```
def detect_face(img):
    flag = False
    face_img = img.copy()
  
    face_rects = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(face_img) 
    
    
    for (x,y,w,h) in face_rects: 
        cv2.rectangle(face_img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,255,255), 2)
        crop_img = face_img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        flag = True
        crop = crop_img.copy()
        crop = cv2.resize(crop,(48,48))
        crop = crop.reshape(1,48,48,3)
        crop = crop.astype('float64')
        pred = model_pred.predict(crop)
        
        n1 = int(np.random.randint(0,256,1))
        n2 = int(np.random.randint(0,256,1))
        n3 = int(np.random.randint(0,256,1))

        text = exp[pred.argmax()]
        cv2.putText(face_img,text,(x,y-30),fontFace = cv2.FONT_ITALIC,
                        fontScale = 2,color=[n1,n2,n3],thickness=7) 
        
        
        crop_img = cv2.resize(crop_img,(227,227))
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(crop_img, 1, (227, 227), MODEL_MEAN_VALUES, swapRB=False)
        
        age_net.setInput(blob)
        age_preds = age_net.forward()
        age = age_list[age_preds[0].argmax()]
        text = 'Age : ' + age
        cv2.putText(face_img,text,(x-20,y+h+50),fontFace = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    fontScale = 1,color=[0,220,0],thickness=3)
        
        gender_net.setInput(blob)
        gender_preds = gender_net.forward()
        gender = gender_list[gender_preds[0].argmax()]
        text = 'Gender : '+ gender
        cv2.putText(face_img,text,(x+w+2,y+int(h/2)+20),fontFace = cv2.FONT_ITALIC,
                    fontScale = 1,color=[0,0,255],thickness=3)

    if(flag):
        return face_img
    else:
        return face_img
```

I have tried so many versions but I am unable to capture a video. I always end up getting this image in a frame.

[image]

I don't understand how or why this is getting captured. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: when you commented the line  `frame = detect_face(frame` do you still get the same issue?

Comment: That's a function that I use to detect faces. I will edit my original post and add that

Comment: yeah but to understand the issue it works fine without it or not

Comment: No, there is no change, the white square has disappeared, the blurry image remains

Answer (score 1):

How about first making sure the camera has captured something?

```
ret, frame = cap.read() 
if ret:
    # run the face detector
else:
    break
```